# How to choose suitable fiber cables for this HDMI Extender?

Tags: hdmi

This is the product: [HDMI Extender via Single SC Fiber
Support 3D/4K2K](http://www.apacoe.com.tw/datasheet/62/AH-UD-200-1SC-XX_V1.pdf)

And this is the cable I want to use: [5m Fiber optic Cable (SC connectors)](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/2pcs-Simplex-SC-UPC-SC-UPC-Transparent-Cable-TAC-0-9mm-PVC-G657A1-Invisible-Cable-5m/1800675_32768663631.html)

I am not sure if the cable is suitable for the hardware. Because the only info about that is seen on the aliexpress is this:

[image: Desc]

And the specification of the HW is this:

[image: HW Desc]

How will I know if they are good match for 4K video transmission? Could you explain technically? Thanks.

Comment: The direct answer to "How to choose suitable fiber cables for this HDMI Extender?" is to read the product information sheet, and then search for products meeting the recommended cable type.

Answer (score 2):

The product information page recommends the following fiber specifications:  9/125 um Single-mode fiber.

I would go with [3mm 10M 9/125um Fiber Optic Jumper Cable SC/UPC-SC/UPC Fiber Optic Patch Cord](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-SM-SX-3mm-10M-9-125um-Fiber-Optic-Jumper-Cable-SC-UPC-SC-UPC/32269334570.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.186.1bXE9t&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10000073_10068_10501_10000074_10503_10000032_119_10000030_10000026_10000023_431_10000069_10000068_10060_10062_10056_10055_10000062_10054_10000063_10059_10099_10000020_10000013_10103_10102_10000016_10096_10000056_10000059_10052_10053_10107_10050_10106_10051_10000097_10000094_10000053_10000007_10000050_10084_10083_10000100_10080_10000047_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10115_10000041_10000044_10078_10079_10000038_10073_10000035_10122_10123_10121_10124-10503_10501,searchweb201603_3,afswitch_2,ppcSwitch_5,single_sort_1_default&btsid=b0b8aa64-6576-4533-b342-27af860a81de).

Meets suggested specs, and is less expensive than the cable you have listed.